# Lambdas and passing a pointer class as argument

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++11, lambda

I'm having problems with passing a class pointer as a parameter in a lambdas callback.

pastebin: http://pastebin.com/SqXHtGDt

How I define the callback:

```
typedef void (*cb_prescription)(Prescription * prescription);
```

How I use the callback:

```
void loop_prescriptions (cb_prescription callback, bool add = true)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= prescriptions->noOfElements(); i++) {
        Prescription * prescription = (Prescription *) prescriptions->removeNo(i);
        if (add) {
            prescriptions->add(prescription);
        }
        callback(prescription);
    }
}
```

I know that everything works, except the parameter pointer part.

```
loop_prescriptions ([&] (Prescription * paper) { paper->something(); });
```

The error I'm getting:

*error: cannot convert ‘list_prescriptions_by_doctor()::’ to ‘cb_prescription {aka void (*)(Prescription*)}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void loop_prescriptions(cb_prescription, bool)’
     });*

Does anyone know how I'm using the parameter incorrectly?
I've tried to add a reference for the pointer as *&, and just removing the pointer, but the List class (yes I must use this) returns a class pointer, so I cannot simply use a copy.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**
I've updated my pastebin based on the answer, which gives a working solution.
http://pastebin.com/7yTPGEQx

Comment: You cannot convert a stateful lambda (that captures anything) to a function pointer.  That is what the error says.  Either don't use (non-global) state, or modify the `loop_prescriptions` signature.

Comment: So i'll need to pass any arguments i need into the lambda scope beforehand?

Comment: no, if you plan to use your callback type and all the classes which use that callback type, you have to use contextless lambdas. Alyernatively, if you need that context, then you need to change the callback type accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to use two lambdas? One where I define the char pointer name (as a config lambda), and another lambda where i will handle the prescription? http://pastebin.com/PF8AZgrp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only accepts function pointers, while you are passing a lambda (or in other words, any random class). Since classes aren't function pointers, most likely would like to accept functors (e.g. Everything which is function like)

I guess you can change your code in 2 different ways:

```
// Using a std::function object; which wraps both function pointers and classes with () operator
using cb_prescription = std::function<void(Prescription*)>;
```

or

```
template<typename cb_prescription>
void loop_prescriptions (cb_prescription &&callback, bool add = true)
```

The first variant is the one that I would prefer, as this is very generic, unfortunately it comes with a performance overhead from wrapping the callback. Unless you are in performance critical code, I would use this one.

The second variant works via templates, so whatever you pass there that can be called with () operator and matching arguments will work. However it requires this code to be available for all callers. Due to the the template, the exact type of the function-ptr, lambda is known, so you will not get the overhead from the std::function.

Comment: Try adding `#include <functional>` and use the correct lambda syntax ´[](){}´

PS: Don't use auto_ptr, it's deprecated, use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Any ideas how I can modify this to make it work with different class names?
using Callback = std::function<unique_ptr(unique_ptr)->void>;